# C++ class prototype not working properly?

Tags: c++, class, declaration, definition, forward-declaration

I'm trying to create a class prototype, however I keep getting the error: 'aClass' uses undefined class 'myClass'

I'm pretty sure I'm making the prototype properly. Using a prototype function works, however class prototype doesn't.

```
extern class myClass;               // prototypes
extern void myFunction();

int main()                          // main
{
    myClass aClass;
    myFunction();
    return 0;
}

class myClass {                     // this doesn't work
public:
    void doSomething() {
        return;
    }

    myClass() {};
};
void myFunction() {                 // this works
    return;
}
```

Comment: `extern class myClass;` doesn't make any sense. The compiler probably told you already.

Comment: @user0042 So why does it work with myFunction and not myClass?

Comment: Because they are different

Comment: There is no such thing as "class prototype". `extern class MyClass;` is an error which your compiler should diagnose.

Comment: Do an empty declaration before main function.  class myClass;

Comment: @KarthikKrish isn't that what I'm doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`myClass aClass;` is a definition, which requires `myClass` to be a [complete type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type); the size and layout of `myClass` must be known at that point, at compile-time.

> Any of the following contexts requires class T to be complete:
>
> - ...
> - definition of an object of type T;
> - ...

That means the class has to be defined before that.

Note that forward declaration works for those cases that don't require the type to be complete, e.g. a definition of pointer to the type (like `myClass* p;`).

For functions the story is different. A function is [odr-used](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) if a function call to it is made, then its definition must exist somewhere. Note that the definition is not required at compile-time, defining it after `main()` (with declaration before) is fine.

> a function is odr-used if a function call to it is made or its address is taken. If an object or a function is odr-used, its definition must exist somewhere in the program; a violation of that is a link-time error.

---

BTW: Using `extern` in forward declaration of a class is superfluous.

Comment: So it isn't possible to have a class prototype since a class is only defined once, which is before main(). Is that what I'm reading here?

Comment: @razorozx For this case, yes, `myClass` must be defined before `main()`. See the addtional infomations added to the answer too.